# Just installed Netbeans and the c++ plugin, but brand new main file already has a error

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans

HI

I recently purchased a netbook for the purpose of being able to code whilst away from home, and everything is pretty dandy, I installed Kubuntu and then netbeans, as netbeans seems to be the better IDE available for linux. I installed the c++ plugin and started a new project, and the IDE is already giving a error:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

The IDE says it can't find cstdlib which would be apart of the standard library i thought

any help on installing the standard library or this cstdlib would be much appreciated, it doesnt look good when a default simple file already has errors

Comment: If you use `#include <stdlib.h>` instead, does it work?

Comment: Can you compile your `.cpp` file using just the command line? Using `g++ helloworld.cpp` for example.

Comment: I run that command and I think it compiled, there was no errros but i cant run the a.out file, terminal just says no such file exists even though the dir command shows that it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install the C++ compiler and its headers as well? By default Ubuntu installs do not have g++ installed. The following command will install stuff essential for development in Ubuntu, like gcc, g++, and headers, and `make`.

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: I didn't install g++, also that command says can't find command

Comment: @Joseph - I think you're missing `aptitude` then, but I updated my response to fall back on using tried and true `apt-get`.

Comment: @Joseph - did you restart Netbeans IDE? It needs to start up with GCC/G++ in your `PATH`, so if you haven't restarted yet, it won't work.

Comment: I did restart, i even restarted the computer, what if netbeans is not looking in the right place? should i reinstall it?

Comment: @Joseph - I'm not certain a reinstall would work. I think you should try reinstall the C/C++ plugin first. If that doesn't work, it's mostly likely due to unconfigured tools. Go to `Tools->Options->C/C++ Compilers` and see if anything has been configured. Otherwise you will have to add a new one for GCC and set your include path, which is going to be something like `/usr/include/gcc/VERSION/`

Comment: ok so netbeans isn't configured with a c++ compiler, i tired looking in /usr/include/gcc but there is no folder called gcc, there is a folder called usr/include/c++ but i dont think thats the right one

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just get the latest update (Tools > Plugins) solved it.